# Getting an error when applying sklearn StandardScaler on Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a DataFrame that has categorical and numerical columns. I am trying to scale the numerical columns as the numbers are pretty extreme. I tried to use the code below but it keeps getting an error. I indicated only the numerical columns to be applied.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

numerical = df.iloc[:, 6:24]
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_df = scaler.fit_transform(df[numerical])
```

The error is
ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64

I don't understand what is causing it. I have tried updating the pandas version that I am using and that did not fix it.

Comment: Your line which defines `numerical` will actually return a `DataFrame`. So check `type(numerical)`. If you run `scaled_df = scaler.fit_transform(numerical)` it will probably work.

Comment: Also if you don't want to hard code the position of your numerical columns you can use `df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])` (if you have `numpy` imported with the alias `np`).

Answer (score 0):

`numerical` is already a dataframe (a subset of `df`), so `df[numerical]` does not make sense here:

```
scaled_df = scaler.fit_transform(numerical)
```

If you try only:

```
>>> df[numerical]
...
ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64
```